# Java stream return 0 if no value

Tags: java, java-stream

Structure of object

```
Account
  Money amount
      Float value;
```

Actually I get sum like that

```
double sum = accounts.stream()
  .filter(x -> x.getBalanceType().equals("120") || x.getBalanceType().equals("120+"))
  .collect(toList()).stream()
  .mapToDouble(y -> y.getAmount().getValue()).sum();
```

If there is not value, it's there a way to return 0 if there is no value

Comment: Can you use .mapToDouble(y -> y.getAmount().getValue() != null ? y.getAmount().getValue()  : 0 )

Comment: By 'there is not value' you mean `value` field is `null`? Why does `getValue` not handle the conversion? Is there really any point in returning `Float` instead of `float`?

Comment: *Curious:* What's the point of `collect(toList()).stream()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you collecting and then streaming again? If the list is empty stream wont do anything

```
double sum = accounts.stream()
       .filter(x -> x.getBalanceType().equals("120") || x.getBalanceType().equals("120+"))
       .mapToDouble(y -> y.getAmount().getValue())
       .sum();
```

An empty list will automatically return 0;

Answer (score 1):

You can use the conditional operator, if the value is not present, you can return 0 in conditional operator.

You can change your map line as

```
.mapToDouble(y -> y.getAmount().getValue() != null ? y.getAmount().getValue() : 0);
```